# Not the same Data Type when I run Migration to current database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, class

I am trying to run an initial migration for my project to a database that already exists.  However, I keep getting this error:

> Column 'dbo.users.u_user_id' is not the same data type as referencing
>   column 'PTEInteractiveCourses.ModifyUserId' in foreign key
>   'FK_dbo.PTEInteractiveCourses_dbo.users_ModifyUserId'. Could not
>   create constraint.

In my database it dbo.users.u_user_id is a numeric type and I have tried decimal, double, and bit.  What data type do I use or do I need to do something else?

here is the code in my class:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [ForeignKey("ModifyUser")]
    [Required]
    public double ModifyUserId { get; set; }
```

Also, I am using 3 existing tables in the database and when I create the migration it creates code to add those tables.  How do I get it so it attaches to those tables but not try to add them in the migrations.

Here is the code to one of them:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain
{
    [Table("users")]
    public class OpsUser
    {
        [Key]
        public double u_user_id { get; set; }

        public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string email_addr { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(30)]
        [Required]
        public string first_nme { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(30)]
        [Required]
        public string last_nme { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid msrepl_tran_version { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(1)]
        [Required]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        [Required]
        public string user_nme { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int u_branch_id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you are referencing a column from one table (entity) to another you need to make sure that it is the same type on both sides of the relationship.

Comment: @Coulton, I understand that but there is no type numeric in C# and in my classes I have used both types.  Unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: Whether it's defined as an `int`, `double` or `float` it needs to be the same.  All three are numeric types and will be reflected by the structure of the database that will be created as a result.  Maybe you need to take a look at what the different numeric types represent and decide which is best for your use case.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: @Coulton, it is a code in the database so there is no decimal and it is 3 digits long.

Comment: An `int` on both sides should be just fine then